# The compact-open topology as an initial topology

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Given $X,Y \in Top$, the compact-open topology on $Y^X$ has a sub-basis consisting of 
sets $V_{K,U}:=\{f\in Y^X: f(K) \subseteq U\}$, for open sets $K\subseteq X$ and compact sets $U \subseteq Y$.

Seeing that $(-)^X$ is a right adjoint in $Set$, we should expect $Y^X$ to have an initial topology in $Top$.

How does one express this as an initial topology?

Comment: When $X$ is Hausdorff locally compact, the compact-open topology on $Y^X$ makes it an exponential object. As exponentiation is a right adjoint (namely $(-)^X$ is the right adjoint of $- \times X$) and right adjoints are final in some sense, I would rather search to view the compact-open topology as a final topology.

Comment: @pece: that makes much sense, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Pece Your conclusion is incorrect – it is a right adjoint so it should have an initial topology, cf products.

Comment: @Lin: Why should we generally expect right adjoints to have initial topologies?